# Tensorflow - weird validation loss behaviour

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

My validation loss is behaving in a very weird way

[image]

What does this behaviour mean?

My network is a simple NN with two hidden layers of 100 nodes each, an input layer with 3 units and an output layer of 50 units. It is used to learn a mapping between a set of 3 coordinates to a time series of 50 time components. There is one and one only time series possible for each triplet of coordinates. The aim is to train the network with a few samples, so that the network learns how to predict the time series associated to a generic triplet of coordinates. This is the network

```
c = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])    
act_f = getattr(tf.nn, 'leaky_relu')

def latent_P(coord):
    h2 = tf.layers.dense(coord, 100, activation=act_f)
    h1 = tf.layers.dense(h2, 100, activation=act_f)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(h1, 50)
    return logits

z_nn_samples = latent_P(c)

recon_loss_nn = tf.keras.losses.MAE(z, z_nn_samples)

loss_nn = tf.reduce_mean(recon_loss_nn)

solver_nn = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss_nn)
```

My training set is made of 3000 time series (with their respective 3000 triplets of coordinates). The validation set is made of 500 time series/ coordinates.

Comment: What do you expect to  happen?

Comment: @pastaleg I guess I would expect the validation loss to go down as well, like the training one does, although possibly with some 'gap' between the two curves due to (hopefully small) overfit

Answer (score 1):

The distributions for training and validation data are different AND/OR you're overfitting.